# What are the test_1 endorser, accuser and baker for?

Tags: docker

I just set up a local enviroment according to https://tezos.gitlab.io/introduction/howtoget.html using the babylonnet.sh

[image: Screenshot of the running docker containers]

I noticed that the babylonnet.sh script runs a test_1 endorser, accuser and baker. What are those docker containers for? Can I just ignore or delete them?